Deleting Loki log chunks from MinIO S3 api
I'm using Loki with MinIO S3 object storage. Since Loki doesn't support size-based retention, is deleting objects directly from MinIO acceptable? Would I need to recalculate the index after deleting S3 objects?
I came across this post, but he's not recalculating the index after deleting objects.
https://support.d2iq.com/hc/en-us/articles/8530002923284-How-to-delete-objects-from-the-Grafana-Loki-MinIO-Object-Storage-backend-with-the-MinIO-client
Currently, I'm using the Loki HTTP delete endpoint but it's a prolonged way of doing it.
